# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PermitsController#show, Couldn't find Permit with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi guys I keep get this error when i try to access to SHOW action(Manage permit button on user/show.html.erb) which should display all the permits of a specific user, i search through all my code and couldn't find the bug. Can you guys help me to check which part i did wrong? Btw I'm implementing a website using Ruby on rails

This is my permits_controller.rb

```
class PermitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_permit, only: [:show, :destroy]
  def index
    @permits = Permit.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
  end

  def new
    @permits = Permit.new
  end

  def create
    @permits = current_user.permits.build(permit_params)
    if @permits.save
      redirect_to invoice_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def destroy
    Permit.destroy_all(user_id: current_user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Permit was successfully canceled.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def confirm
    @fields = %i[vehicle_type, carplate, studentid, name, department, permitstart, permitend]
    @permit = current_user.permits.build(permit_params)
    render :new and return unless @permit.valid?
  end



  def show
    @permits = Permit.where(:user_id => current_user.id)


  end

  def update
    @permits = Permit.where(user_id: current_user).take
    respond_to do |format|
      if @permits.update(permit_params)
        format.html { redirect_to root_path}
        flash[:success] = "Permit successfully updated"
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    @permits = Permit.find(params[:id])
    #@permits = Permit.find_or_initialize_by(user_id: params[:id])
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_permit
    @permits = Permit.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def permit_params
    params.require(:permit).permit(:vehicle_type, :name, :studentid, :department, :carplate, :duration, :permitstart, :permitend)
  end
end
```

This is my permits/show.html.erb

```
<%= @permits.name %>
```

This is my route.db

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :permits do
    collection do
      post :confirm
    end
  end
  resources :visitor_permits
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'invoice' => 'permits#invoice'
  get 'payment' =>'transaction#new'
  get 'show_visitor_permit' =>'visitor_permits#show'
  get 'show_permit' =>'permits#show'
  get 'visitorpermit' => 'visitor_permits#new'
  post 'createpermit' => 'permits#create'
  get 'homepage/index'
  post 'permits' => 'permits#create'
  get 'permitapplication' => 'permits#new'
  get 'adminlogin' => 'admin_controller#index'
  get 'patrollogin' => 'patrol_officer_controller#index'
  get 'createcitation' => 'citations#new'
  get 'contact'=> 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
  post 'users' => 'users#create'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new' #Page for a new session
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create' #Create a new session
  delete 'logout'=>'sessions#destroy' #Delete a session


  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

users/show.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="sidebar">
<ul id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <li><%= link_to "New Parking Permit", permitapplication_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Manage Permit", show_permit_path(@permit) %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "New Visitor Parking Permit", visitorpermit_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Manage Visitor Permit", "#" %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Check Fines", "#" %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "New Health and Safety Report", "#" %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Manage Health and Safety Report", "#" %></li>
</ul>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess you're clicking on a `link` to go to the specific `Permit`. Can you post that link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can remove the :show method in before_action as it will invoke two queries.

Then if you add where condition in active record query (like below), it will results the array of records instead of single record.

```
@permits = Permit.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

So you can not directly put the below line in your view as array of objects will not permit access the name parameter directly.

```
<%= @permits.name %>
```

May be you can iterate all the records like below and populate the name of every Permit object.

```
<% @permits.each do |permit| %>
   <%= permit.name %>
<% end %>
```

Or you can do some thing like below to show it as comma separated.

```
<%= @permits.map { |f| f.name }.join ',' %>
```

If you want the first object alone in the @permits you can use like below.

```
<%= @permits[0].name %>
```

P.S: Note that it will throw an exception if the first object doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the reply man! I'll try your solution, but I'm interested on how to iterate all the records and populate the data of permit object. What should I input to make that happen?

Comment: I have edit my answer. Check it out to iterate objects.

Answer (score 2):

In `PermitsController` you have have wrote the before action to set the permits

```
  before_action :set_permit, only: [:show, :destroy]


  def set_permit
    @permits = Permit.find(params[:id])
  end
```

So, while setting permits if permit is not present with specific `id` in DB it will raise an exception `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`

you are also setting permits in show action

```
  def show
    @permits = Permit.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
  end
```

not sure why you are setting permits twice for show action.
 - first time in `set_permit` method
 - and second time in `show` method

Can you please add parameters in question which are passing with the request.

Assigning record twice is not good practice. In your case in before action you are finding `Permit` by `id` and if record for that specific `id` is not present in the database then it will raise a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception. so you have to check what you are passing in `params[:id]`.

If you want to set permits based on the current user you can skip `set_permit` for show action.

And in show action if you are assigning `activerecord collection` instead of `active record` in that case in view you have to iterate over the collection object to print the `permit` details. Or if there is only one permit for user you can set `active record` object in show action instead of `active record collection`

Comment: So the repeating is causing the problem? I'm not sure about how the before_action works because I'm following a step by step guide. I tried to remove the :show from the before_action it works. So are you claiming that the setting permits in show action are the same as the before_action?

Comment: @GaryVlc No - repeating is not a problem - actually repeating is not good practice. in your case in before action you are finding `Permit` by `id` and if record for that specific `id` is not present in the database then it will raise a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception. so you have to check what you are passing in `params[:id]`.

Comment: In this case I'm pasing the permit ID right? So what should I input to iterate over the collection of my object? And how to handling the error?